# Alert Message not showing in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have got a contact form that is build using Laravel 5.4, parsley.js and Bootstrap 3, it works fine but it does not display a success message at the top of the form on successful delivery of a message or display any errors in case there is an error. Please assist?

**Contoller**

```
public function postIndex(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, array(
                'name'    => 'required|min:10',
                'email'    => 'required|email',
                'message'    => 'required|min:100'
            ));

        $name = $request->name;

        $data = array(
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'bodymessage' => $request->message
            );
        Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
            $message->from($data['email']);
            $message->to('info@kapsol.com');
        });

        Session::flash('success', 'Hello $name, Your Form was successfully sent');

        return redirect()->route('pages.index');
    }
```

**Index.blade.php**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">

{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'index.post', 'class' => 'contact-form', 'data-parsley-validate' => '')) !!}

<div id="success">
<div class="col-sm-12">
@if(Session::has('success'))

<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> 

<strong> Success: </strong>  {{ Session::get('success') }}

</div>

@endif

@if(count($errors) > 0)

<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> 

<strong> Errors: </strong>
<ul>
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
<li> {{ $error }} </li>   
@endforeach
</ul>

</div>
@endif
</div>
</div>

{{ Form::text('name', null,  array( 'placeholder' => 'Name...', 'class' => 'input', 'required' => '', 'minlength' => '10'))}}

{{ Form::email('email', null,  array('placeholder' => 'Email Address...','class' => 'input', 'required' => '', 'type' => 'email'))}}

{{ Form::textarea('message', null,  array('placeholder' => 'Message...', 'class' => '', 'required' => 'input', 'minlength' => '100')) }}

{{ Form::submit('Submit') }}

{!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

**Route**

```
 Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex') ->name('pages.index');
    Route::post('/', 'PagesController@postIndex') ->name('index.post');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting to the same route your form is posting. I assume that the route that render the view is a GET route and have another name, you should redirect to that route or the route that renders index.blade.php

Comment: ,,, I have rectified the route and used the one for displaying the form but still the error messages dont show,,,, Could it be an error with my Bootstrap code

Comment: maybe you can post your routes file and your whole controller

Comment: ,,, Check it out I have updated my query with new routes and the controller but the problem persists

Comment: Try using session method in the request object. Like this `$request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');`

Comment: Still no progress @Franco

Answer (score 0):

This is why you have the `with()` method to chain the `route()` method on. So rather than use `Session:flash()`, you can simply add a `with()` method that flashes that message to the session for the next request:

```
return redirect()->route('pages.index')->with('success', 'Hello'. $name.', Your Form was successfully sent');
```

Or rather if your form was originally from the `index` page, then you simply don't have to remember the name of the route, simply use `back()` helper method, i.e:

```
return back()->with('success', 'Hello'. $name.', Your Form was successfully sent');
```